# Finding the code generating the menu with links

Tags: navigation

Where is the code that generates the menu and links shown in the following photo?

[image]

Comment: [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu/) could.

Comment: What's the problem you want to solve?

Comment: i want to extract the menu and links to create a custom navigation

Comment: Is there a reason that you need the code? You can build a new menu with custom links without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_link/7#comment-24463